How do I calculate the probability distribution of momentum assuming that my instrument has a small spatial extension?
Let us consider a particle in a one-dimensional space (X-axis) whose state, at a given instant of time, is described by a given wave function.
Let us assume that we measure the momentum p using a measuring instrument that interacts with the particle exclusively in a small interval of the X-axis, for example in the interval [x1,x2], while the wave function extends (is not zero) in a larger interval (even extremely larger).
Let us assume that the instrument is able to interact with the particle and therefore obtains a result for the value of p (with relative uncertainty).
Is it correct to say that to calculate the probability distribution of the p (using the usual Fourier transforms) we must use exclusively the portion of the wave function within the interval [x1,x2]?
How do you get the new wave function after the measurement?
Is the following statement correct?
The change that the wave function undergoes can be obtained by considering two sudden different measurements, first a measurement of the position that (if the particle is found in the interval) causes the function to collapse (and its cancellation outside the interval [x1,x2]) and then a measurement of the momentum that causes a further collapse (which depends on the values ​​of p found).

One way to carry out this experiment and illustrate some quantum strangeness is diffraction through a pinhole. You take a laser and point it at a screen with a slit in it. Some light hits the screen. Some makes it through and hits a second screen.
A typical laser is a light source where photons all have the same state. They form a Gaussian Beam which is almost perfectly collimated. There is a few milliradians of spreading. The beam intensity has a central maximum and fades away as you get farther from the beam axis. Almost all of the beam is within a centimeter or so of the axis.
All the photons in the beam are in the same state. This does not mean they all follow the same trajectory. If you turn down the intensity so much that only a single photon is in the beam at a time, you would see spots of light appear on the first screen as individual photons hit. Occasionally you would see spots of light appear on the second screen. The spots on the second screen are more spread out than the first screen.
Photons that hit the first screen fall mostly fall close to the beam axis. Some hit farther away. You conclude the wave function of the photons is concentrated near the beam axis, where the photons are most likely to be found.
The pattern grows slightly if you move the first screen far away. You conclude that photons are traveling almost parallel to the axis. The momentum vector is almost parallel to the axis.
The uncertainty principal prevents perfect alignment to the axis. It prevents you from making the beam diameter $0$. There will always be some uncertainty in the sideways component of momentum and sideways component of distance from the beam. You cannot predict in advance where any photon will hit the screen.

The pinhole and second screen are your instrument that interacts with the photons over a small spatial extent to measure their momentum.
All the photons that went through the pinhole are known to have a small range of possible sideways positions. Each photon strikes some measured position on the second screen. You can measure the sideways distance as it traveled between the screens, with an accuracy limited by the size of the pinhole.
The sideways displacement tells you the sideways component of momentum. Given the laser wavelength, $\lambda$, the momentum of each photon is $h/\lambda$. The photon traveled a distance $d$ between the screens and a distance $y$ sideways. The sideways component of momentum was $hy/\lambda d$.
A small pinhole constrains $\Delta y$ to a small value. The uncertainty principle says that $\Delta p$ must necessarily be large. You can see that in the larger measured $y$ values.

All photons in the original beam are in the same state. They all have a wave function as large as the original beam.
The pinhole did not select photons whose wave functions happened to be where the pinhole is. The screen and pinhole measured range of positions of each photon and returned one of two outcomes. If the range was found to be inside the pinhole, the entire photon passed through. Otherwise the entire photon was absorbed.
The photon did not act like a classical wave here. Some of each wave would have passed through. It did not act like a classical particle. A particle would not have had its momentum changed by missing the screen. It behaved a bit like both. This is a problem because it leads you to expect classical behavior. It causes confusion when the actual behavior is sort of like, but actually different from, anything you have seen in the classical world.
The photon is like a wave and unlike a particle in that the measurement involves the entire width of the beam. Each point contributes to the outcome, to the probability of passing through.
The photon is unlike a wave and like a particle in that the outcome is all or nothing. The photon goes through or is absorbed. But thinking of a point particle whose position must be one point is wrong.
Nothing classical has a spread out cause and a random all-or-nothing outcome like this. Trying to understand the outcome with classical cause and effect doesn't work.
A measurement occurred when the photon arrived at the screen/hole. If the outcome was that it passed through the hole, the photon has a new state defined by a new wave function. To get the new function, set he parts of the old wave function that arrived at the screen to $0$ and leave the parts that arrived at the hole unchanged. Then multiple the new function by a constant to normalize it.
The new wave function can be used to calculate probabilities when the photon arrives at the second screen.

Nice answer (+1) I wonder if I rub a comb on my hair (making the comb negatively charged) and wave the comb with my hand, then I am generating some electromagnetic ripples using the comb source, correct? Can this electromagnetic ripple be considered a "photon", and if not, what special source conditions are required before we can generate a proper "photon" instead of an arbitrary electromagnetic ripple?

Thanks mmesser, the diffraction experiment through the pinhole is a very clear answer to my question.
This experiment proves that what I said at the end of my question is correct, that is, that for the particle that arrives on the second screen, the probability distributions relative to the various observable quantities must be deduced exclusively from the portion of the wave function that passes through the hole.
In practice, the new wave function is the one obtained from the first wave function that is collapsed for the measurement of the position (position of the pinhole).

@James - Electromagnetic waves are many photons. The charge on a comb is strong enough to attract small pieces of paper. If you wave a comb, you might jiggle the paper. The wavelength is about $1$ Hz. $E = h \nu$. Photons with that wavelength have truly tiny energies. It takes a lot of them to jiggle paper.

@mmesser314 thank you. Can there be tiny crumbs of electromagnetic ripples which are not photons? I have seen the photon defined as an "electromagnetic wave packet", this seems to imply that some tiny ripples which are not in the structured form of a wave packet will not qualify as a "photon", even though the ripples exist in the electromagnetic field?
